# Linear independence of real powers of x

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, real-numbers

I know that integer powers of x are linearly independent. I would expect that fractional powers of x (eg. $x^{n/2}$) are also linearly independent. But what about real powers of x? If I could use any amount of any power of x WITHOUT using, say, $x^{2.5}$ could I somehow create $x^{2.5}$?

can I find an $f(n)$, $f(2.5)=0$ such that

$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(n)x^ndn=x^{2.5}$

Comment: Just FYI, the term "linear independence" typically implies _finite_ linear combinations. But disregarding terminology I think this is a nice question.

Comment: Note that the restriction $f(2.5) = 0$ doesn't have any effect on the value of the integral, assuming $f$ is a function (as opposed to a generalized function, in which case it's still not clear what it means to write $f(2.5)=0$ as opposed to, say, $f=0$ in some neighbourhood of $2.5$).

Comment: @grdgfgr Are you already aware that finite linear combinations of real powers of $x$ cannot add up to a different power of $x$?  This isn't clear from your question.

Comment: I am aware that finite linear combinations cannot add up to a different power of x. Infinite powers can't either? If I have two taylor series on two sides of an equal sign, coefficients must match.